# How to update Ads when AMP-Carousel swiped or navigation buttons clicked

Tags: amp-html

Say that I have 5 ads placed across the taller page, Is there a way to refresh/reload/update all (or any) the Ads that's embedded using AMP-Ad or AMP-Embed on the page when AMP-Carousel is swiped (on mobile) or AMP-Carousel's left and right navigation buttons clicked.

**Edit-1**

Of-course I never though about using JS as I knew that I cannot added custom JS other than what's offer in AMP API, here are the URLs that I found talking about the same issue and seems like this feature is not doable or kinda in development.
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4038
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4038

Mean while here is what I did to accomplish my task, I placed Ad in each carousel item and changed the layout of carousel to display ad and carousel image, the good thing about AMP is that it loads Ad only on going to next slides.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no mention of this in [amp-ad documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad) as no 3rd party Javascript is allowed to run:

> "No ad network provided JavaScript is allowed to run inside the AMP
>   document. Instead the AMP runtime loads an iframe from a different
>   origin (via iframe sandbox) as the AMP document and executes the ad
>   network’s JS inside that iframe sandbox."

Answer (score 0):

You have not the common usage of AMP, as you need to do re-rendering of the page. So, probably, the answer is "there is NO Ability to do this" because of specs of AMP.

But, just an idea, if you can use [AMP-List](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/) and update it basing on an event, it may work.
Also, You can try to use [AMP-Live-List](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-live-list/) for this, but not sure if you're able to reload it by an event.